# UIButton remove border with overlay on touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I need a UIButton but I don't want a border for it.

However I still want to keep that nice gradient overlay when somebody touches the button

Like on the Facebook iPad app, the text links they have in the News Feed which show a gray box overlay when you touch them.

I saw a solution on here about using a UISegmentedControl. However I don't want to have to use gradients/the Quartz framework in the solution.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

UPDATE

Here's an illustration
[image]

(1) is before you touch (2) is what happens when you touch the button.

I basically just want to replicate this effect, I guess a transparent 'overlay', like what happens when you touch a button, but without a border.

Comment: Maybe include a screenshot for those of us who don't use Facebook?

Comment: [link]http://tinypic.com/r/160tmo/6

(1) is before you touch
(2) is what happens when you touch the link. 

I basically just want to replicate this effect, I guess a transparent 'overlay', like what happens when you touch a button, but without a border

Comment: Please refrain from using the `xcode` tag for questions not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[yourButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
[yourButton setTitle:@"like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

// Round corners? Requires Quartzcore framework
[yourButton.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[yourButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[yourButton.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a UIImage in the color you want, and call `setBackgroundImage:forState:` for the highlighted state (the button is highlighted when the user taps it);